# how to export information resource from project professionnal to project online

Tags: project, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013, project-online

I create project on project online, but I use project professional for create resource, I don't know how to export resource on project online , can you help pls

Answer (score 0):

In Project 2013 & 2016, on the Resource tab click on Add Resources. At the bottom of that menu there should be a selection for "Import Resources to Enterprise". Click on that and follow the directions of the wizard that is launched.